# Airflow command to stop all dag executions

Tags: python, airflow

I'm looking for a way to stop all dag runs from CLI in airflow. In particular, I would like to do something like marking all running executions as `Mark Failed` in the UI, but I want to do it from CLI. It can be a bash or python script. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe you can update task instances state from the database, but I woud not encourage.

Answer (score -4):

You *could* kill all airflow scheduler processes, i.e. like this:

```
sudo pkill -9 -f "airflow scheduler"
```

This would stop all running DAGs and the scheduler itself. I haven't tested this and I think it's not the best idea - the task instances most likely don't get updated anymore if the scheduler itself is getting killed.